# How can I define a clojure type that implements the servlet interface?

Tags: servlets, clojure, java-interop, deftype

I'm attempting to use deftype (from the bleeding-edge clojure 1.2 branch) to create a java class that implements the java Servlet interface.  I would expect the code below to compile (even though it's not very useful).

```
(ns foo [:import [javax.servlet Servlet ServletRequest ServletResponse]])

(deftype servlet [] 
   javax.servlet.Servlet 
   (service [this 
         #^javax.servlet.ServletRequest request
         #^javax.servlet.ServletResponse response]
   nil))
```

But it doesn't compile.  The compiler produces the message:

```
Mismatched return type: service, expected: void, had: java.lang.Object
  [Thrown class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

Which doesn't make sense to me, because I'm returning nil.  So the fact that the return type of the method is void shouldn't be a problem.  For instance, for the java.util.Set interface:

```
(deftype bar [#^Number n] java.util.Set (clear [this] nil))
```

compiles without issue.

So what am I doing wrong with the Servlet interface?

To be clear: 
I know that the typical case is to subclass one of the servlet abstract classes rather than  implement this interface directly, but it should still be possible to do this.

**Stack Trace:**

The stack trace for the (deftype servlet... is:

```
Mismatched return type: service, expected: void, had: java.lang.Object
  [Thrown class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]

Restarts:
 0: [ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.

Backtrace:
  0: clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceMethod.parse(Compiler.java:6461)
  1: clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceExpr.build(Compiler.java:6119)
  2: clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceExpr$DeftypeParser.parse(Compiler.java:6003)
  3: clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:5289)
  4: clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5110)
  5: clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:5071)
  6: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5347)
  7: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5334)
  8: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5311)
  9: clojure.core$eval__4350.invoke(core.clj:2364)
 10: swank.commands.basic$eval_region__673.invoke(basic.clj:40)
 11: swank.commands.basic$eval_region__673.invoke(basic.clj:31)
 12: swank.commands.basic$eval__686$listener_eval__687.invoke(basic.clj:54)
 13: clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:365)
 14: foo$eval__2285.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE)
 15: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5343)
 16: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5311)
 17: clojure.core$eval__4350.invoke(core.clj:2364)
 18: swank.core$eval_in_emacs_package__320.invoke(core.clj:59)
 19: swank.core$eval_for_emacs__383.invoke(core.clj:128)
 20: clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:373)
 21: clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:169)
 22: clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
 23: clojure.core$apply__3776.invoke(core.clj:535)
 24: swank.core$eval_from_control__322.invoke(core.clj:66)
 25: swank.core$eval_loop__324.invoke(core.clj:71)
 26: swank.core$spawn_repl_thread__434$fn__464$fn__465.invoke(core.clj:183)
 27: clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
 28: clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
 29: clojure.core$apply__3776.invoke(core.clj:535)
 30: swank.core$spawn_repl_thread__434$fn__464.doInvoke(core.clj:180)
 31: clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:398)
 32: clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
 33: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try without any type hints:

```
(deftype servlet []
  javax.servlet.Servlet
  (service [this request response]
    ...body...))
```

From [the web page about deftype](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/clojure/Datatypes):

> - if you leave out all hints: will try
>     to match on same name/arity method in
>     interface(s)
>
>   - this is preferred
>   - if you supply any hints at all, no inference is done, so all hints (or
>       default of Object) must be correct,
>       for both arguments and return type

And from `(doc deftype)`:

> If not supplied, they will be inferred, so type hints should be reserved for disambiguation.